# PyGtk - set checkbox in the treeview of a specific row invisible

Tags: python, tree, treeview, gtk, pygtk

I would like to make the checkbox in the node "parent 1" and "child 1 of parent 1" invisible. Do you know how to solve this issue?
I am still struggling with the modifying cell renderers for a specific row and not for the entire column.

[image]

This is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# example basictreeview.py

import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')
import gtk

class BasicTreeViewExample:
    # close the window and quit
    def delete_event(self, widget, event, data=None):
        gtk.main_quit()
        return False

    def __init__(self):
        # Create a new window
        self.window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)

        self.window.set_title("Basic TreeView Example")

        self.window.set_size_request(200, 200)

        self.window.connect("delete_event", self.delete_event)

        # create a TreeStore with one string column to use as the model
        self.treestore = gtk.TreeStore(str)

        # we'll add some data now - 4 rows with 3 child rows each
        for parent in range(4):
            piter = self.treestore.append(None, ['parent %i' % parent])
            for child in range(3):
                self.treestore.append(piter, ['child %i of parent %i' %
                                              (child, parent)])

        # create the TreeView using treestore
        self.treeview = gtk.TreeView(self.treestore)

        # create the TreeViewColumn to display the data
        self.tvcolumn = gtk.TreeViewColumn('Column 0')

        # add tvcolumn to treeview
        self.treeview.append_column(self.tvcolumn)

        # create a CellRendererText to render the data
        self.cell = gtk.CellRendererText()
        self.cell1 = gtk.CellRendererToggle()

        # add the cell to the tvcolumn and allow it to expand
        self.tvcolumn.pack_start(self.cell, True)
        self.tvcolumn.pack_start(self.cell1, True)
        # set the cell "text" attribute to column 0 - retrieve text
        # from that column in treestore
        self.tvcolumn.add_attribute(self.cell, 'text', 0)

        # make it searchable
        self.treeview.set_search_column(0)

        # Allow sorting on the column
        self.tvcolumn.set_sort_column_id(0)

        # Allow drag and drop reordering of rows
        self.treeview.set_reorderable(True)

        swH = gtk.ScrolledWindow()
        swH.set_policy(gtk.POLICY_AUTOMATIC, gtk.POLICY_AUTOMATIC)
        swH.add(self.treeview)
        self.window.add(swH)

        self.window.show_all()

def main():
    gtk.main()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    tvexample = BasicTreeViewExample()
    main()
```

I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add an attribute for visible and put the bool in your treestore, when adding rows just put it to false when adding a child row.

```
gtk.TreeStore(str, bool)

self.tvcolumn.add_attribute(self.cell1, 'visible', 1)

self.treestore.append(None, ['parent %i' % parent, True])

self.treestore.append(piter, ['child %i of parent %i' %
                                          (child, parent), False])
```

This should roughly be what you need to change.

Do notice I don't know python's syntax all that well (I used the C# bindings for GTK)

Comment: thanks for your fast answer and your effort! it works :)
do you also know how to add 3 checkboxes in a row?
like   x [ ] y [ ]  z [ ]

Comment: Just repeat the same thing you did, create a checkbox and pack it inside a column (You can also pack multiple inside the same column)
They can also all point to the same "visible" property column if you so desire

Comment: Thank you, you helped me a lot!